# Change background each time onClick function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change background each time onClick is called and remove previous tab background, but when I try to do so the previous onClick effect stays

**Here is the Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  }
</script>


<a href="#home" class="tabs">
  <li id="a" onclick="myFunction" class="tabs-li">Home</li>
</a>
<a href="#about-us" class="tabs">
  <li id="a" onclick="myFunction" class="tabs-li">About Us</li>
</a>
<a href="#contact-us" class="tabs">
  <li id="a" onclick="myFunction" class="tabs-li">Contact Us</li>
</a>
```

Comment: replace to `onclick="myFunction()"`

Comment: done that no change, no matter which onClick is clicked it changes background of element with id="a"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Zeroth Law:** An `id` shouldn't be duplicated.

**First, learn HTML.** It is annoying for every HTML guy to see non-semantic tags.

You should nest the tags correctly. Hit the person you taught this. Also, the most blundered and ill-fated *W3Schools*, (***NEVER I RECOMMEND***), which is hated by everyone also doesn't do this mistake.

> **Wrong:**
>
> ```
> <a><li></li></a>
> ```
>
> **Right:**
>
> ```
> <li><a></a></li>
> ```

**Second, the `onclick`.**

You need to add `()` at the end.

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

**Fourthly, you are generalizing.**

I have recently seen a lot of developers doing this. Instead, why not just use a simple `:hover` in CSS, without JavaScript. Let's see **without JavaScript**:

```css
li:hover {background-color: lightblue;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

For your way, using JavaScript, using `onclick()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $("li").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
  });
  $("li a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("li").css("background-color", "lightblue");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Finally, what you need:**

```js
$(function () {
  $("li").click(function () {
    $("li").removeAttr("style");
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
  });
  $("li a").click(function () {
    $("li").removeAttr("style");
    $(this).closest("li").css("background-color", "lightblue");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: done that no change, no matter which onClick is clicked it changes background of element with id="a"

Comment: secondly I want to apply anchor to whole li tag

Comment: @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty Sorry, check out the **zeroth law** please.

Comment: Solution please! if don't have one please stop commenting.

Comment: @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty Added solution. Please tell if it works. Let me know what you want further.

Comment: Please tell if it works. Let me know what you want further. Happy to help you and know better HTML. @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty...

Comment: Yes, I know that id is unique but if I call different functions, the previously called function's effect stays

Comment: tell me easy way to unbind effect of previous using jquery

Comment: @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty Check the updated JavaScript code. Should work for you.

Comment: @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty See the final answer please.

Comment: Also share some light on "Whats wrong in using <a><li></li></a> ?"

Comment: Do you understand the following? **The HTML List Item Element (`<li>`) is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`).**

Comment: If you understood the above comment, I am happy for you @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty, finally you understood what's wrong and how to do! `:)`

Comment: sorry i missed that part while posting, my original code contains that <ul> as I was eliminating extra classes etc that's missed it

Comment: Simple thing. UL can contain only LI. And LI can be contained only inside UL or OL. Okay?

Comment: I missed the <ul> </ul> tags while posting here, anyways thanks, can't vote untill my reputation is 15. Thanks to your initial answer that caused me -4 reputation :3

Comment: Don't be hasty brother I have clicked it this is what I get

Comment: "Thanks for feedback, once your reputation reaches 15 your votes will change publically"

Comment: @SıkándàrÅlıÇhışhty Thank you so much... Hope it helped you. Sorry for all the trouble. `:)`